# Smarter Touch in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

One of the issues I have been having with the `FlatList`, and `TouchableHighlight` is making it feel like it is a 'news' feed. If you open up an app like twitter and scroll down the timeline, while every row is selectable, it uses some sort of smarter touch listener and does not act pressed when touched when it can tell that you are scrolling

Right now a render row for me looks like:

```
<TouchableHighlight>
   <Text>Press Me </Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Is there some sort of smarter touch events way to put this together.. maybe even with `TouchableWithoutFeedback`.. does this make sense?

Comment: do you want to touch a component without any feedback?

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827809/delay-in-responding-touch-events-when-flat-list-scroll