# Delay in responding touch events when flat list scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have implemented Infinite scroll using FlatList in react-native application. This list is a carousel and can be considered a long list.

When I am scrolling the list My touch event outside list is not responding at the instance it was clicked but responds when scrolling of FlatList is finished.

How can I improve this?

Comment: you have to provide more context what's probably happening is that you're not updating your flattest efficiently and that's blocking your click as you have too many rerenders

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard answers to this because we don't see your code, try to apply these recommendations to put data on FlatList maybe you needed.

https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/